# AutoMapper Memory Leak

Tags: memory-leaks, automapper, c#-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

AutoMapper is taking too much memory. I think it's a memory leak.

I'm using 11.0.1 version in .Net Core 6 framework.

I've profiled the project. Here are a couple of screenshots:
[image]

**Memory Usage reaches up to 2 GB by the Web API**

[image: Memory Usage reaches up to 2 GB by the Web API]

Any ideas as to why it is taking this much memory for around 400 mapping classes?

Here's the configuration of AutoMapper being applied from the static IServiceCollection class:

```html
    services.AddAutoMapper(
            cfg => cfg.AddMaps("WebApi.Common"),
            typeof(MapperProfile),
            typeof(VendorProfile));
```

Comment: Try the [MyGet](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/The-MyGet-build.html) build.

Comment: But other than that, you're probably misusing it. See https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu How am I misusing it? Can you please be specific?

Comment: I wouldn't know that, it's your own code, but the number of type maps should be 400, not whatever you have there. If you follow the docs and the example there, you should be allright.

Comment: @JackXandar we can only guess how you are misusing it cause we don't have any access to the code.

Comment: @GuruStron sorry about that. I have added the configuration. Do you see any problem with that?

Comment: @JackXandar without seeing actual profile it's hard to say. My guess would be that you are storing in some GC root some internal automapper stuff due to it's being used in the mapping. But that's very wild guess.

Comment: Where did you see code like that? Certainly not in the docs. Once you'll write a proper config, I'm sure you'll see everything working properly.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu you're absolutely right. I got it fixed after configuring it through latest documentation. The previous configuration was based on an old version of AutoMapper which was causing the leaks. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by configuring AutoMapper according to the latest documentation.

Below is the code that fixed this issue:

```cs
var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
{
    mc.AddMaps("WebApi.Common");
    mc.AddMaps("WebApi.Core");
});

IMapper mapper = mapperConfig.CreateMapper();
services.AddSingleton(mapper);
```

Previously, it was configured according to the documentation of an older version of AutoMapper.